# Can Plex Server turn on at a pre-set time?

Tags: sleep

I have found Plex Media Server to be very resource hungry.  My CCleaner recommends putting it into Sleep mode which is fine wile I'm on the PC.  I swap rooms with my wife about 5PM everyday (pc still on) but with Plex in sleep mode I no longer can access Plex on my TV.  My simple solution would be for Plex to automatically launch at 5PM every day.  Even a way of launching it from my Android phone would be useful.  Any ideas guys?

Comment: Don't use CCLeaner https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCleaner#Data_collection & https://portswigger.net/daily-swig/backdoor-attack-hits-two-million-ccleaner-users it is owned by Avast (yuck). use Bleachbit instead https://www.bleachbit.org/

Comment: Because you haven't specified an OS I am going to assume it is Windows. You can use the Task Scheduler that is built in to Windows https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10 this guide is for win10 but its very similar on other versions

Comment: Plex Media Server shouldn't be very resource-hungry if it's doing nothing. Which resources are being used? Are you sure that it's not just refreshing its library?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Plex server has several processes running
with some child processes: Plex Media Server, Plex DLNA Server,
Plex Tuner Service and Plex Update Service.

You could kill all of them using using the command:

```
Taskkill.exe /T /F /FI "IMAGENAME eq PLEX*"
```

This command might stop something like seven Plex processes in all.

To restart the Plex server, start `PlexMediaServer.exe`, which
might be found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\plex\plex media server`.

If the two above commands work for stopping and starting Plex,
store them in `.bat` files and create scheduled tasks for running them.

For creating Scheduled tasks, see for example
[How to create an automated task using Task Scheduler on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10).

Comment: Yeah thats what I said, see above.

Comment: @Gantendo: Yes, I found the same link as first on Google for Task Scheduler.

Comment: lol last time you said you didn't see my comment. Why do people turn my comments into answers?

Comment: @Gantendo: I beg to differ, but your comment wasn't an answer and it isn't the important part in my answer. I can find another link if that bothers you. I did see that you gave the same link as I found, but I didn't think that would cause a problem

Comment: You beg to differ on what topic? I am not mad, I am curious why people do that, and this is the 2nd time I've noticed you do it. No need to get defensive; I really don't care about silly rep points, you can have em lol

Comment: @Gantendo: On the fact that I turned your comment into an answer. I don't use Plex, and it took some searching to find what processes need to be killed and how to restart Plex.

Comment: Ah, yeah that's some bonus info that OP didn't ask for. I prefer posting comments because some people (you probably know who they are lol) get really fussy about what an answer should be (to them). Plex is pretty cool actually you should check it out. I can recommend it.

Comment: @Gantendo: It's not a bonus info, since without it task scheduling has nothing to do. Note: I use Serviio and it does the job. I'll look into Plex if I decide to give it up. Thanks.

Comment: As always there is a huge difference between the answer to the question and what OP needs to know ;-) I'll check out Serviio thanks!